# Artin Chapter 2, exercise 2.2: avoiding circularity

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, monoid

I'm worried that my answer to this exercise from Artin's book is trying too hard to balance avoiding verbosity with avoiding circularity. The exercise is:

> Let $S$ be a set with an associative law of composition and with an identity element. Prove that the subset consisting of the invertible elements in $S$ is a group.

The result is clear, but each of the verifications is hard to do precisely. For example, every element of $S$ has an inverse *in* $S$, but I need to check that that inverse actually is invertible. The check for closure is analogous. I want to say that the identity element and associativity are inherited, but I can't do that unless I verify that I actually have a valid law of composition on the subset, and I'm trying to do that without making the argument circular and using associativity. I suppose I can do this, as long as I make clear that I'm performing the computation *in $S$.*

I'm trying to balance rigor with elegance, and I think I'm much worse at the latter, so I would appreciate some feedback. Here is my attempt.

> Let $S^{\times}$ denote the set of invertible elements of $S$. I claim that $S^{\times}$ is a group. We first check that $S^{\times}$ is closed. Let $a,b \in S^{\times}$. We will show that $ab \in S^{\times}$. Thus, $a$ and $b$ are invertible in $S$, so there exist $a^{-1}, b^{-1} \in S$ such that $aa^{-1} = e$ and $bb^{-1} = e$ in $S$. But $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ and $(b^{-1})^{-1} = b$, so $a^{-1}, b^{-1} \in S^{\times}$. Furthermore, $b^{-1} a^{-1} \in S$. Performing the computation in $S$ and using associativity, we have
> $$
> (ab)(b^{-1} a^{-1}) = (a(bb^{-1}))a^{-1} = (ae)a^{-1} = aa^{-1} = e
> $$
> and
> $$
> (b^{-1} a^{-1})(ab) = (b^{-1} (a^{-1} a))b = (b^{-1} e)b = b^{-1} b = e.
> $$
> So $ab$ is invertible in $S$, with inverse $b^{-1} a^{-1}$, so $ab \in S^{\times}$. But $(b^{-1} a^{-1})^{-1} = ab$, so $b^{-1} a^{-1} \in S^{\times}$, so $ab$ admits an inverse in $S^{\times}$. Therefore, $S^{\times}$ has a well-defined law of composition, namely the restriction of the law on $S$. Associativity is immediately inherited from $S$. Notice that $ee = e$ by definition, so $e = e^{-1} \in S^{\times}$. We've already checked inverses. If $a \in S^{\times}$, then $a^{-1} \in S$, but $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$, so $a^{-1} \in S^{\times}$, so $S^{\times}$ is a group.

I think I've managed to check all of the axioms without making any circular arguments, but the argument is incredibly messy. I'd appreciate any advice on how to improve this proof.

Comment: I don't find the argument messy. I find it quite natural and clear.

Comment: Such a set $S$ is called a *monoid*.

Comment: Associativity happens on $S$; you only need to show that the product of two things in $S^{\times}$ is also in $S^{\times}$, by proving that their product **in $S$** lies in $S^{\times}$. As such, you are perfectly fine doing the calculations in $S$ and using associativity in $S$. There is no circularity involved.

Comment: Do you assume that inverse elements are right inverse or two-sided inverse?

Comment: @PaulFrost An earlier exercise asked for verification of various properties of inverses, so I'm assuming Artin wants me to work with two-sided inverses here.